# Wikimapia API Display Map

Tags: python, wikimapia

I'm really new to APIs, and I decided to work on the Wikimapia API to see how APIs really work. I'm currently doing research at Carnegie Mellon and the research supervisor instructed me to get started with the API and figure out how it works etc. For now, I have to input the latitude/longitude which will display a map of 500m^2 around it. This will be used for a self-driving jeep to complement what the sensors on-board the car can perceive.

Anyway, so I downloaded pymapia and used the box function, but all it did was return this:

```
>>> print box(40.444663, -79.943036, 40.444842, -79.939774)

query http://api.wikimapia.org/?function=box&key=7758C23C-47DA8BA3-4205B7F8-57EB8EDD-A0808F25-F570C462-959B517B-51410DC3&bbox=40.444663,-79.943036,40.444842,-79.939774&format=json&page=1&count=50
{u'count': 50, u'language': u'en', u'has_deeper_tiles': False, u'version': u'1.0', u'found': 0, u'folder': [], u'page': 1}
```

What do I do with the output? This makes no sense whatsoever.. :(

Answer (score 0):

You're calling just the base URL of the API. The [API documentation](http://wikimapia.org/api) has more information on what to do. You need to pass additional parameters (such as `lon_min/max` and `lat_min/max`) to actually get more data. You'll have to play around a bit to get the data you want.